# Chalitza to wife? (Qidushin 3b)

Tags: talmud-gemara, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, maseches-kiddushin, hermeneutics

Talmud Qidushin 3b

> סד''א תיתי בקל וחומר מיבמה מה יבמה שאינה יוצאה בגט יוצאה בחליצה, אשה שיוצאה בגט אינו דין שיוצאה בחליצה ... ספר כורתה ואין דבר אחר כורתה
>
> [You could think ... if a yevama that cannot go out by a *get*, goes out by *chalitza*, a regular wife that goes out by a *get*, a fortiori she could go out by *chalitza* ... No, we learn from the verse that only the *act* cuts and no other thing]

What is the idea that, unless the מיעוט, chalitza would make sense, or be efficient, on a wife? But chalitza is tailored specifically for a brother-in-law, not for a husband!

The yevama begins saying מאן יבמי the yavam responds, and finally after she spit:

> ככה יעשה ... בית **אחיו**

Some remarks after the comments/answer below:

- These sayings are not *mandatory*. However, if the yavam or yevama *cannot* say them (because they are mute), the chalitza is not OK, in virtue of the principle of כל שאינו ראוי לבילה בילה מעכבת בו. Meforshim explain this principle: ok, tora said to do something, if occasionnaly you didn't, it is not catastrophic; but if there is a case where this thing *cannot* be done, one *is no more in the field of application of this law*. So, here, the sayings making no sense, this principle show us that chalitza *was not defined* here.
- Seems very difficult to change the sayings to adapt them in every situation: you see the tora wants these precise words to be said, and only in Hebrew (Sotah beginning of perek 7).
- In Tosfot, they ask why don't say the *qal vahomer* to free an אמה העבריה. Even there is a מצות יעוד on her, she is primarily a servant, so that her master profit from מעשה ידיה : an *economical* relation. It is more difficult to see here a *divorce*.
- How, at all, we can begin the *qal vahomer* ומה יבמה שאינה יוצאה בגט etc ... So what?.. *Get* is weak?! How can we think that a *get*, that permits an אשת איש, would be weaker than chalitza?! If get don't work on yevama, there must be something particular, but never because of *weakness*!
- Why don't say פירכא: מה ליבמה שכן איסור לאו, תאמר באשת איש שיש בה מיתה

Comment: It could be that the suggestion is for the the mechanics of chalitzah (removal of shoe and possibly also spitting) together with a modified declaration appropriate for a husband. No source though...

Comment: Bear in mind that the sayings are not me’akev. See Yevamot 12:3

Comment: I think the idea is that _chalitza_ seems to be "stronger" than a _get_. A _yevama_, is somehow so attached to her _yevam_ that a _get_ doesn't work to separate them but still _chalitza_ does. So in the case where a _get_ *does* work (i.e. a regularly married couple), _chalitza_ should certainly work.

Comment: @JoelK But if they *can* speak, it is meakev (see Yev 104b כל שאינו ראוי לבילה) and here they *cannot* say these words because it makes no sense...

Comment: @Daniel Yes, *this* is indeed the qal vachomer. But here it is like saying "ומה יבמה שאינה יוצאה בהגבהה יוצאה בחליצה, מיטלטלין שנקנין בהגבהה אינו דין שיקנו בחליצה" ...

Comment: @yO_ That's not equivalent. Getting divorced is not a similar case to an object being acquired. The _svara_ relies on the idea that _chalitza_ is a _type_ of divorce which requires an extra strong method of separation (_chalitza_).

Comment: A get permits an אשת איש but it doesn't permit a יבמה while חליצה does permit a יבמה.

Comment: @Daniel Okay. ...so? Does this show that *get < chalitza* ? If "yes": That would say that one need more power to free a yevama than a wife: absurd!! (Wife > yevama, obviously) ; If "no": so what is the logic that chalitza must work on a wife?

Comment: @yO_ "wife > yevama, obviously". I disagree that that's obviously true. Why do you say it is? After all מה יבמה שאינה יוצאה בגט יוצאה בחליצה...

Comment: @Daniel Edited the question (the פירכא) to address your remark ;)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the idea that, unless the מיעוט, chalitza would make sense, or be efficient, on a wife? But chalitza is tailored specifically for a brother-in-law, not for a husband!

What it means to say, is that a wife would do Chalitza on her husband, just like it's done on a brother-in-law.

While, in the Torah, chalitza is introduced for a brother-in-law, that doesn't mean that the same concept can be used for others.

> The yevama begins saying מאן יבמי the yavam responds, and finally after she spit:
>
> ככה יעשה ... בית אחיו

The lashon would obviously be changed to something more appropriate for this case.

Comment: "The lashon would *obviously* be changed" IMHO it is not obvious... Edited the question.

Comment: You do have a point that the lashon comes from the tora, and therefore how can we change it. I'll try to think of a case where we take a concept from the tora, and we then change it a bit to fit our case